# ogrinfo error in R: No GDAL installation found

Tags: r, package, gdal, rgdal

I simply want to use a get capabilities method using the function ogrinfo from the gdalutils package in R, but there seems to be a problem with the package install

This is the first time that I try this in R so I might be missing something obvious. I tried this simple code:

```
dsn <- "WFS:http://geomap.reteunitaria.piemonte.it/ws/gsareprot/rp- 
01/areeprotwfs/wfs_gsareprot_1?service=WFS&request=getCapabilities"

ogrinfo(dsn, so=TRUE)
```

I get the following:

> NULL
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan = ignore.full_scan, verbose = >verbose) :
>    No GDAL installation found. Please install 'gdal' before continuing:
>     - www.gdal.org (no HDF4 support!)
>     - www.trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ (with HDF4 support RECOMMENDED)
>     - www.fwtools.maptools.org (with HDF4 support)
>
> 2: In gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan = ignore.full_scan, verbose = >verbose) :
>    If you think GDAL is installed, please run:
>   gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)

That's the first time I use this package so I'm not sure to understand. Do I need to install gdal? I installed the rgdal package, if that matters.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you need to install GDAL. If you are on windows, the osgeo installer is usually the easiest choice. If GDAL is already installed, try `gdal_setInstallation(ignore.full_scan=FALSE)`

Comment: Ok fair enough I'll try that then, thank you